# Knex:Error Pool2 - Error: connect ECONNREFUSED

Tags: node.js, express, bookshelf.js, knex.js

I am working with Node.js, Express.js, Bookshelf.js and Knex.js

I am getting following error with default knex pool definition.

```
Knex:Error Pool2 - Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
```

That is with following knex definition (default pool.min value is 2)

```
var knex = require('knex')({
            client: 'mysql',
            connection: config.connection,
});
```

I get error

```
Knex:Error Pool2 - Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
Knex:Error Pool2 - Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
```

Where as it works fine with following definition.

```
var knex = require('knex')({
            client: 'mysql',
            connection: config.connection,
            pool: {
                    min: 0,
                    max: 10
            }
});
```

I noticed that the error is printed n number of times where n in pool.min value.

Can someone please tell me why this is happening. Although, error is resolved but since I am newbie, I am not able to understand why this is happening.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ECONNREFUSED is returned by the connect() system call when the remote system or service is either not listening on the specified port or a  firewall between you is making it appear so.

Basically, knex is unable to connect to the database server.  The reason why you don't get the error with pool.min is 0 is because the pool2 library is satisfied with zero active connections and will not attempt to connect to the database until a connection is needed by knex.

---

To follow up, the knex folks [don't](https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/issues/407) seem to [care](https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/issues/448) to implement [this](https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/issues/545).  Furthermore, the issue seems to be that the Pool2 object is destroyed when ECONNREFUSED is encountered at startup and knex is just not able to recover from it.

That being said, the issue only occurs for me at startup.  If the database goes down /after/ the pool is established, knex will keep trying to connect until it comes back up.  Something in either knex or the mysql client library handles the reconnect case just fine, even if ECONNREFUSED is returned.  With that in mind, what I've taken to doing is this:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    knex.raw('SELECT 1').catch(function (error) {
        log.fatal('caught exception trying to issue database keep-alive');

        // do something fatal, like exit or cluster.worker.disconnect()
    });
}, 0);
```

I do this *immediatey* after I create the knex object.  Fail fast.  This works for me, but YMMV.

Comment: I understood. Although pool.min 0 satisfies my requirement, but is there a way it can work with pool.min > 0 ?

Comment: I added the workaround that I'm using with some success.  It's not perfect -- in fact, I find it rather disgusting -- but it works.

Answer (score 1):

As diz says, that's the error you see when knex can't connect to the database.  When I was getting that error, it was because I did not have a MySQL server running on my localhost (my 'host' in the connection object) that had a database on it with the name indicated in the 'database' key of the connection object.  I fired up MySQL and created the empty database and everything was great from there.  Here are the steps I wrote out for my fellow devs:

**MySQL steps required before this runs:**

1. mysql.server start
2. mysql -u root
3. CREATE USER 'our_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'our_password';
4. CREATE DATABASE dbname;
5. GRANT ALL ON dbname.* TO 'our_user'@'localhost';

Comment: Yes, I understood the problem. You are correct. But I still am not able to run it for pool.min more than 0. Although, I don't require it to keep > 0 for now, but still would like to know if there is a way out.

Answer (score 0):

I have a local setup where Knex gets instantiated through an SSH tunnel using [tunnel-ssh](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tunnel-ssh).

In my case, the issue was **the opposite** to the one described by the OP. I.e., after adding `pool: { min: 0, max: 7 }` to Knex' instantiation as suggested by the [current version of the docs](https://knexjs.org/guide/#pool)...

> Note that the default value of min is 2 only for historical reasons. It can result in problems with stale connections, despite tarn's default idle connection timeout of 30 seconds, which is only applied when there are more than min active connections. It is recommended to set min: 0 so all idle connections can be terminated.

... I started to get `ECONNREFUSED` errors.

Going back to not overwriting the pool minimum (i.e. using default of `2`) solved the issue.